VSCode: Mimic cursor usage to adjust view sizes with keyboard shortcuts
As title states, I wish to mimic the behaviour of using the mouse pointer to drag and adjust the horizontal and vertical lines surrounding the editor windows using only keyboard commands in VSCode.
The closest thing I've managed is to utilize the commands:
"command": "workbench.action.increaseViewSize"
"command": "workbench.action.decreaseViewSize"

Which respectively increases and decreases the active window with a set amount of space (left and right for sidebar + editor, and up/down for terminal).
One problem with this solution is that the terminal window increases and decreases when adjusting an editor window. I want the terminal to keep its size.
Additionally, I want to be able to customize how much space is adjusted, to get the "fine-grain" precision the mouse yields.
Ideally, what I am looking for is something as a command that snaps to the bars between the windows, and from there being able to use i.e. the arrow keys to adjust the window sizes.
